# Show view at taped button inside UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working on an iOS app which contain a collectionview, inside this collectionview I have a button, as follow:

```
ViewController
-UICollectionView(myColl)
--UICollectionViewCell
---UIButton (myButton)
-UIView (myView)
```

What I want to do is to show `myView` under `myButton` when I tapped it, what I try is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TestCell", 
          for: indexPath) as! TestCell
   cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showEditView), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

and in `showEditView()`

```
@objc func showEditView(sender:UIButton!)  {
        let position: CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.myColl)
        myView.center = position
}
```

But that wasn't worked, what can I do to get that?

Comment: Just to clarify, `myView` is contained in your  `UICollectionViewCell` and on selection you want the view to appear behind the selected cell? 
should `myView` stay behind your `UICollectionViewCell` if you scroll as well? or just on the selection?

Comment: No, it's not UICollectionViewCell,I want it appear just on the selection, and hide when scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @objc func showEditView(sender:UIButton!)  {
        let position: CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.collectionview)
        let indexPath = self.collectionview.indexPathForItem(at: position)
        if indexPath != nil {
         myView.center = position
        //if your view is hidden
         myView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use protocol in your UICollectionViewCell for it. It's healthier than use forge using.

```
protocol YourProtocolDelegate {
   func showEditView()
}

class YourCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  var delegate: YourProtocolDelegate!
  var button = UIButton()
     override init(frame: CGRect) {
       button.addTapGestureRecognizer {
         self.delegate.showEditView()
       }
     }
}
```

Of course you must take inherit from your protocol to your ViewController class

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, YourProtocolDelegate {
}
```

After that you can reference your cell's protocol to your viewcontroller.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TestCell", 
      for: indexPath) as! TestCell
   cell.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: That is only to call function, that is not my question, my question it's how to show a uiview at tapped button's position?

Comment: Okay i'll edit my post for add presenting a view but i must know that your view where must be shown? Inside cell or inside viewcontroller but near of cell? Can you give more info about?

Comment: Its appears inside viewcontroller above tapped cell, under tapped button.